# How to print all palindromes upto 1000 without using any String,StringBuilder?

Tags: java, palindrome

I have to write a code for printing all palindrome numbers up to 1000. Here is my code. I have dealt with 3 scenarios:

1. 1-digit number
2. 2-digit number
3. 3-digit number

My third scenario is not printing just the palindromes but prints all the numbers. A hint will help me solve this.

```
public class PrintPalindrome {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Integer[] array=new Integer[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        array[i]=i+1;
        printPalindrome(array[i]);
        //System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}

public static void printPalindrome(Integer a)
{
    String num=Integer.toString(a);
    int length=num.length()-1;
    //System.out.println(num);
    if(num.length()<=1)
    {
        System.out.println("" + num);

    }
    else if(num.length()==2)
    {
        if(num.charAt(0)==num.charAt(1))

            System.out.println(num);

    }
    else if(num.length()>2)
    {
        //now deal with the numbers whose length is greater than 2
        for(int i=0;i<=length;i++)
        {
            if(num.charAt(i)==num.charAt(length-i))
                System.out.println(num);


        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Is suspect some parenthesis mistake if(num.charAt(i)==num.charAt(length-i))

Comment: I would suggest abandoning this approach and simply using a `String` representation of the `Integer` in a `StringBuilder` and the `reverse` method. Two lines for code and works for an `Integer` of any length.

Comment: i made those changes. Does not help

Comment: (1) Why do you want wrapper classes `Integer` instead of `int`? (2) Do you really need array here, wouldn't simple `i` be enough? (3) What `""+` is doing in `System.out.println("" + num);`, is it needed there? (4) If length of word is 3 then do you really need this `for` loop to iterate over all digits? HINT: which digits in number `ddd` should be equal to make it palindrome?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: What if I am not allowed to use reverse function in StringBuilder? Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Work out a solution with arithmetic…

This doesn't necessarily help with the code that you've already got, but it's approach to the problem in the title, **How to print all palindromes upto 1000**, which may be helpful to others who come across this question. It's often fun to try to solve these problems using the properties of the numbers, without worrying about converting them to strings.  In this case, note that for any number *n*, you can get the leading digit by *n % 10*, that is, the remainder of *n* divided by 10, or *n* modulo 10.  You can get the number whose digits are the same as the remaining digits of *n* as the integer quotient of *n/10*.  E.g.,

1234 % 10 = 4
1234 / 10 = 123

Now, if you keep applying this deconstruction, you can get the individuals digits:

123 % 10 = 3
123 / 10 = 12

12 % 10 = 2
12 / 10 = 1

1 % 10 = 1
1 / 10 = 0

Now, if you take those numbers in the same order that you got them (4, 3, 2, 1), you can reconstruct the "reverse" number:

1 + 10(2 + 10(3 + 10(4 + 0))) = 4321

If we call this the reverse of a number, then number is a palindrome if and only if it's equal to it's reverse.

### …and then translate it to Java

This is fairly straightforward to implement in Java, and it doesn't require any special casing about 1-digit numbers, 2-digit numbers, etc., or string manipulation. (As [Kent points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984654/how-to-print-all-palindromes-upto-1000/23985063#comment36959223_23985063) in the comments, there's still a limit on how large the numbers that this handles is, but if you need to handle big numbers, you could (i) switch to a `long`; (ii) switch to a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).)

```
public class PalindromeExample {
    /**
     * Returns the number whose digits (base 10) are the reverse
     * of number's (with no leading zeros).
     * @param number the number to reverse
     * @return the reversed number
     */
    public static int reverse( int number ) { 
        int result = 0;
        while ( number > 0 ) {
            result = result * 10 + (number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Show the numbers less than 10000 whose digit sequences
     * are palindromes.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {
            if ( i == reverse( i ) ) {
                System.out.println( i );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
0
1
2
3
…
9
11
22
…
99
101
111
…
151
161
…
8008
8118
…
9339
9449
9559
9669
9779
9889
9999
```

Comment: nice, but keep in mind, if we put it in a generic solution, reversing a number might lead to overflow. but this solution is very nice. +1

Comment: @Kent Right;  this is limited to smaller numbers.  It wouldn't be too hard to swap in [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), though.

Comment: @user3400060 If it worked for you, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you want, although you might want to rephrase the question a bit, since this doesn't really address your original code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(num.charAt(i)==num.charAt(length)-i)
```

is wrong. Even if you set parenthesis in the "right" place you still be wrong, because for example:

```
charAt(0) == charAt(3) //and what's char at 3?

if(num.charAt(i)==num.charAt(length-i-1))
```

should do the trick but then placing it in a for loop doesnt make any sense.

When a 3-digit number has 1st and 3rd digit the same it is actually a palindrome. Every other loop will just mess up your output.

Comment: please check the code. I have tested with the suggested code also. Does not work!

Comment: It is probably too late for me. You are saying in your answer that it is incorrect, while I read it as correct :/. My mistake, you are right. Will remove my comments.

Comment: @user3400060 read the answer, not just copy-paste code. It's not supposed to work and I explained why it doesn't make sense, on many different levels. If you have further question feel free to ask, but I don't give trivial answers that easily, just for learning purpose. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For the requirement, we don't have to convert to string.
pls try if this works for you: (could be an one-liner)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) 
    if (i<10 ||(i<100&&i%11==0)||(i>100&&i%10==i/100) )
        System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to check whether the number is a palindrome or not before you print it. You just need to seprate checking and printing like this:

```
if(num.length()>2)
    {
        boolean isPalindrome=true; 

        for(int i=0;i<=length/2;i++) //you compare one half, to the other
        {
            if(num.charAt(i)!=num.charAt(length-i)) 
                isPalindrome=false;

        }

        if(isPalindrome)
            System.out.println(num);

    }
```

This should work for a number of any length.

Answer (score 0):

Handling scenarios for each digit length to check if a number is a palindrome is not an appropriate approach.

Trying what the other answers suggest - like going through each and every number and checking if it is palindrome by reversing number digit by digit is better but even then it is not very efficient as it is brute force.

So, I would like to some suggestions if I may:-

- Rather than going for brute force, any other approach if possible is preferable.
- Even while resorting to brute force, using the library functions is
  better and at least as efficient as any code we can write. ex - Integer.reverse() function for reversing an integer.

I have had a try at generating the palindromes(rather than trying one by one). This is not bug-proof yet as I have not tested extensively but should be able to convey the concept.

```
public class PrintPalin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //The first palindrome  = 1
        int i = 1;
        while(i<=10000){
            System.out.println(i);
            i = nextPalin(i);
        }

    }
    static int nextPalin(int i){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i));
        int len = sb.length(), right = len/2, left;
        if(len%2!=0 || len == 1){
            left = right;
        }else{
            left = right-1;
        }
        //System.out.println(left + " " + right);
        while(right<len && sb.charAt(right)=='9'){
            sb.setCharAt(right, '0');
            right++;
            sb.setCharAt(left, '0');
            left--;
        }
        if(right==len){
            sb.insert(0, '1');
            //sb.append("1");
            sb.setCharAt(right, '1');
        }else{
            sb.setCharAt(right, (char)(sb.charAt(right)+1));
            if(right != left){
                sb.setCharAt(left, (char)(sb.charAt(left)+1));
            }
        }

        i = Integer.valueOf(new String(sb));
        return i;
    }
}
```

Where the above approach wins is when the density of palindromes per number tried is less when we go for higher numbers but for the range that is asked(0 to 1000) it would not be able to make much difference.

I am open to other approaches. I was thinking may be  decoding the addition required to generate the next palindrome number should be faster and better approach instead of using strings the basic idea of both approaches are similar so should not be much difficult(though I am not sure).